# Posting a SE site URL in chat results in old logos being oneboxed

Tags: bug, status-review, chat, onebox, logo

When posting a link to a site's homepage in chat, the link automatically oneboxes to the site's logo.

However, I discovered a couple of related bugs with it. First, the logo for beta sites has been modified so that the word "Beta" is now capitalized, rather than all-lowercase "beta". When I post a link to such a site in chat, the [old logo featuring the word "beta" in all-lowercase and the old color is posted](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7648913#7648913). This [also applies](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7648915#7648915) to newer sites that were created after the changeover.

Additionally, when posting a link to a site that was redesigned, in some cases the old logo for that site is posted. For instance, the Android Enthusiasts site was massively redesigned, with a new color theme and new logo (some time before the responsive designs began rolling out). However, the link posted in chat [still uses the old logo](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7648914#7648914). I couldn't reproduce this for all sites, however; for Stack Overflow, the [new five-bar solid color logo is posted](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7648911#7648911), rather than the old six-bar gradient logo.

Is it possible that the onebox system can load the site's logo live, rather than from some really old cache that hasn't been updated in a long time (and may only be manually updated)? Also, why is the old lowercase "beta" logo posted even for newer sites created after the network-wide design changes, which included changing the site's logo to have the word "Beta" capitalized instead?

Comment: From what I understand, which is only a partial understanding... It's not a cache. It's just a separate set of artwork that has to be manually changed. The artwork is designed to be used as part of the chat room... and the [Android chat room styling](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android-enthusiasts) is still green, so the logo is still green... and SO's logo changed a long time ago. The other ones that aren't updated are ones that changed relatively recently as part of the unified themes change... It's not so much a bug... but I don't know what to call it.

Comment: @Catija The fact that new beta sites created *after* the design change show an old logo means it's a bug. Those sites *never* had the logos that the chat system oneboxes them as having.

Comment: No. It just means that we're still using the same tool when we create the logos. Also, beta site. There's only one that's been created since the site redesign.