# Is the change in the site logo in Chat intentional?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat, logo

I remember [Math.SE Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com) looking like this:

> From [web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20211025203733/https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com):
> [image: A list of Math Stack Exchange chat rooms. In the top left there is a small logo with a 6 red squares logo and the text "Mathematics"]

Now, it looks like this:

> [image: A list of Math Stack Exchange chat rooms. In the top left there is the 6 red squares logo, much larger than in the previous screenshot]

To be exact, the logo changed from [this](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/math/Img/logo.png?v=dc):

> [image: A logo with 6 red squares followed by the text "Mathematics"]

to [this](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/math/Img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=dc):

> [image: A larger logo with six red squares]

From the sources, it seems like `apple-touch-icon.png` replaced `logo.png`.

---

I don't think this is intentional. Is it?

Comment: The same is true in TeX.SE, Physics.SE, Biology.SE. Not sure for the other sites. That is what I am familiar with. If I am correct, replacing [site-name] in https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/[site-name]/Img/logo.png?v=dc where [site-name] is from [site-name].stackexchange.com should give the "right" logo in Chat.

Comment: Also true for MathOverflow.

Comment: As of now, the chat that I encountered which is not affected is Meta.SE.

Comment: @soupless and chat.stackoverflow because they are on different servers.

Comment: Also happening on the chat page itself: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7LPO.png I presume because it's the same image?

Comment: @Shadow why [tag:bug] tag? It might be a by-design feature. I quite like it.

Comment: I believe the site name used to be displayed in the bottom-right of a chat room you're in (to the right of the chat text box) as well, which may be tied to the same potential issue.

Comment: Same on Stack Overflow where the icon is now much larger.

Comment: Same on chat.meta now.

Comment: @Randal'Thor because this is not pretty and appears to be just some dev mistake. In case it's on purpose, there is the [tag:status-bydesign] exactly for this.

Comment: Related: [The link to the main site from chat is too small to click on a mobile, without difficulty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372116/the-link-to-the-main-site-from-chat-is-too-small-to-click-on-mobile)

Comment: This appears to be network wide. It could be fixed by **1)** removing the inline style `max-width: 150px`, and **2)** adding a `width: 30px` style in Stacks.css as a replacement.

Comment: @TylerH Shouldn't it be that some `logo.png` should be `apple-touch-icon.png`?

Comment: @soupless No, I shouldn't ever see something named `apple-touch-icon`, because I don't access SO from any Apple devices. Even on mobile I am using an Android device. I'm guessing the design team made an icon-only version of apple-touch-icon and copied the styles from it (150px width makes a lot more sense for something with a long site name).

Comment: I am not sure about how this works, but when I inspected the element, that was the name. See the one I linked from web.archive.org.

Comment: Looks like [tag:status-completed], at least [on SO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D14KP.png)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### tl;dr

That was my bad, sorry for the confusion. You should see full logos in chat again for sites that have custom designs. Sites that are using the shared default site design will still have the icon only.

#### But why?

First, some background. All Q&A sites and styles follow the same pattern in terms of the assets they need and where they are located. One of those assets is `logo.png` and over the years it has been almost entirely deprecated. The sites themselves have switched over to serving `logo.svg` for sites that have a custom design or rendering the site name in text for sites that don't. The only remaining uses of `logo.png` were in chat and in email templates.

A couple weeks ago I deployed a change that removed the dependency on `logo.png` from the email templates. I then removed all `logo.png` files for sites that don't have a custom design... and discovered that the API provides `logo_url` as part of the [Site object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site). No problem, I thought - I'll just add a fallback to serve the `icon_url` when `logo_url` is unavailable.

In hindsight, this is obvious, but the API project doesn't have access to the same file system location as Q&A, so basically it considered all logos unavailable. :) Chat fetches the site list from the API, so that's how we got to replacing logos with icons.

(Side note: `apple-touch-icon` is just a filename. I don't know if it has origins in something Apple-specific, but at the moment for us it's synonymous with "the site's icon" across all devices.)

#### Okay, but really, why now?

We're building more tools to empower [the CM team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-is-on-the-community-management-team-and-what-does-it-do/99341#99341) to handle parts of the site lifecycle that previously required a developer. One of those tools is automating the removal of the "public beta" status. So we built a shiny new tool that allows a CM to "graduate" potentially multiple sites at the same time. With the logos in place, they'd also need to edit them themselves to remove the word "beta" or coordinate with someone in design... and that's more overhead than necessary for images that are barely even used, as I mentioned above.

#### Going forward

We want to keep moving away from `logo.png`. The next steps here are likely to make chat grab and display SVG versions instead and improve the treatment that sites without a custom design get. The API may start pointing at SVGs as well, though we'll still need some sort of fallback for sites without a custom design.

Comment: That site object and those fields sounded familiar so I hoped on a side-(site?)-effect that [this bug](https://stackapps.com/q/9028) might have been fixed as well. Maybe a next time ;) Cheers for building stuff to support the CM team.

Comment: I think [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326420/posting-a-site-url-in-chat-results-in-old-logos) was also partially fixed as a result of your change... *some* site homepage oneboxes no longer show old logos. It would be nice if you answered that, especially since you gave it a review tag back then.