# The link to the main site from chat is too small to click on a mobile, without difficulty

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat, mobile-web

I predominantly use Stack Exchange chat on my mobile phone, in desktop mode.

Since the change documented here: [Is the change in the site logo in Chat intentional?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371935/is-the-change-in-the-site-logo-in-chat-intentional) the link, which is now *just* the logo, and not the logo and text, has been too small for me to click on easily without zooming in.

Here is how that part of chat looks on my phone now:

[image: Screenshot of the lower right side of desktop view of Stack Exchange chat, with the site logo acting as a link to main site]

Using [What is my screensize](https://viewportsizer.com/what-is-my-screen-size/) My viewport size is '412 × 652', and I'm on a [OnePlus A5000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnePlus_5).

Please can something be done to make navigating to the main site from chat easier?

Comment: Its even worse on MSE chat. The logo is *invisible*

Comment: It's not mainly on mobile-web, probably. I think it's for all.

Comment: @soupless, could you suggest an edit to make that clearer? I'm aware the logo change has effect all versions of chat (i.e. not just mobile-web) but the difficulty in clicking a small icon is much more difficult on a mobile device.

Comment: This bug was caused by the same issue as the duplicate and when one was fixed, they both were. I've closed as a duplicate and marked as completed.